# Finding First Variation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Given the functional $ I(U) = \int_0^1 F(u'(x),u(x), x) dx$

and: $F(p,u,x)= \sqrt{p^2+u^2}$

how would you find the first variation using say the definition on Wikipedia (Gateaux Derivative) and what's the purpose of it? I know the Euler-Lagrange tell you the functions which make the given functional stationary, but I'm not quite certain how to relate these two ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$\begin{align}I[r]&=\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}L(\theta,r,r')\mathrm{d}\theta\\
L(\theta,r,r')&=\sqrt{(r')^2+r^2}\text{.}\end{align}$$

Write
$$L(h)=L(\theta,r+h\delta r,r'+h\delta r')$$
where $h$ is a scalar. If $L$ is differentiable at $h=0$ for constant $\theta$, $r$, $r'$ $\delta r$, and $\delta r'$, then
$$L(h)=L(0)+h L'(0)+o(h)$$
where
$$L'(0)=L_{,r}(\theta,r,r')\delta r+L_{,r'}(\theta,r,r')\delta r'\text{.}$$

Then 
$$\begin{split}I[r+h\delta r]&=\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}L(h)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\left(L(0)+hL'(0)+o(h)\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=I[r]+h\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}L'(0)\mathrm{d}\theta +o(h)\text{.}
\end{split}$$
and
$$\begin{split}\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}L'(0)\mathrm{d}\theta&=
\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\left(L_{,r}(\theta,r,r')\delta r+L_{,r'}(\theta,r,r')\delta r'\right)\mathrm{d}\theta \\
&=\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\left(L_{,r}(\theta,r,r')-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}L_{,r'}(\theta,r,r')\right)\delta r\mathrm{d}\theta+\left.L_{,r'}(\theta,r,r')\delta r\right\rvert_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\text{.}
\end{split}$$
For each function $r$, the right side of this last equality is a linear functional in the function $\delta r$: call it $\nabla I[r]$:
$$\langle \nabla I[r],\delta r\rangle\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\left(L_{,r}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}L_{,r'}\right)\delta r\mathrm{d}\theta+\left.L_{,r'}\delta r\right\rvert_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\text{.}$$
Then
$$I[r+h\delta r]=I[r]+h\langle\nabla I[r],\delta r\rangle + o(h)\text{;}$$
$\nabla I[r]$ is precisely the Gâteaux derivative (or first variation) of $I$ with respect to $r$. Note that $\nabla I[r]$ is composed of two terms:

- a "bulk" term $\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\left(L_{,r}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}L_{,r'}\right)\delta r\mathrm{d}\theta$—this vanishes for all $\delta r$ if and only if the Euler—Lagrange equations hold; and
- a "boundary" term $\left.L_{,r'}\delta r\right\rvert_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}$—setting this to zero gives us boundary conditions for the Euler—Lagrange equation if the endpoints of the variation [are not fixed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312724/how-to-apply-euler-lagrange-equation-when-end-points-are-not-fixed?rq=1).

Frequently, one encounters minimization problems in mechanics in which boundary conditions are not fixed—using *all* of the first variation instead of just the Euler—Lagrange equations tells us what those boundary conditions should be.